# Creating qubit operators for optimization problem

Tags: quantum-algorithms, qiskit

There is `DOcplex` module that generates `WeightedPauliOperator` for the [DOcplex Model](http://ibmdecisionoptimization.github.io/docplex-doc/mp/docplex.mp.model.html) by calling docplex.get_operator(model). I want to understand what are the steps for creating the qubit operators (List of `WeightedPauliOperator`) without DOcplex module?
As I understand it is necessary to map problem to QUBO form.